# Docpad error 'length' of undefined

Tags: undefined, docpad

My [config](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/docpad.coffee)

After "docpad run" produces [errors](https://gist.github.com/npofopr/7827199)

What could be the problem?

I tried to remove "docpad-paged", but don't result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that getPageUrl is complaining that there is not a post for the Id -1 [here](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/src/documents/posts.html.eco#L41)

You need to change [this line](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/src/documents/posts.html.eco#L37)
to

```
<% for pageNumber in [0..@document.page.count-1] by 1: %>
```

the change here is **by 1** as it will prevent coffee-script automatically going from 0 to -1 when there are no pages to loop.

Comment: I'm change this line, but fetch [new error](https://gist.github.com/npofopr/7827199#comment-965302)

Comment: your new problem is because relatedDocuments is undefined https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/8731f57ba10487759da0c64a793cab38d5fc899b/src/layouts/post.html.eco#L46

Comment: looking at the [docpad-plugin-related](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-related) it's example code does this instead `<% for document in @getRelatedDocuments(): %>`